# Why do we join our hands in the way we do, when we pray?

Tags: culture, tradition, prayer

Whenever we pray, we tend to keep our hands together. 
Is there a reason why we do so ??

Comment: Namaste is derived from Sanskrit and is a combination of two words, **"Namaḥ"** and **"te"**. **Namaḥ means 'bow','reverential salutation' or 'adoration' and te means 'to you'**. Therefore, Namaste literally means "bow to you" translated as **"I bow to you"**. We bow to god whenever we pray so that his blessings are on us and he fulfills the wish.

Answer (score 0):

There are two verses in the Bhagavad gita that talk about that, 11.35 and 11.14. You can see it at http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11/35 and http://www.vedabase.com/en/bg/11/14
And the word describing this practice is *kṛtāñjali*, meaning "*one who joins the hollowed palms in reverence or to solicit a favour (holding the hollowed palms together as if to receive alms or an offering), standing in a reverent or respectful posture*".
Arjuna did it to offer obeisances to the Supreme Lord Krishna.
Today we are also doing the same because it's a common practice in Hindu dharma as we see from the above Gita verses and other scriptures.