# Meaning of Namaste (Folded hands)

Tags: rituals, samskara

Why do we join hands while praying or greeting or even when we apologise? What are the origin and significance of this practice?
[image]

Comment: Here is my answer: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11623/why-do-we-join-our-hands-in-the-way-we-do-when-we-pray/11632#11632

Comment: Part of the question is duplicate. You might want to keep only the first question here.

Answer (score 1):

> In Sanskrit the word is namah + te = namaste which means “I bow to you” - my greetings, salutations or prostration to you. The word ‘namaha’ can also be literally interpreted as "na ma" (not mine). It has a spiritual significance of negating or reducing one's ego in the presence of another. In Kannada, it is called Namaskara and Namaskaragalu; in Tamil, Kumpiṭu; in Telugu, Dandamu, Dandaalu, Namaskaralu and Pranamamu; in Bengali, Nōmōshkar and Prōnäm; and in Assamese, Nômôskar.

[Source](http://hinduism.about.com/od/artculture/p/namaste.htm)

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism SE! ,You should cite sources.

Comment: ma does not mean mine. na mama means not mine. ma has a different unrelated meaning in Sanskrit.

Comment: Thank for the meaning of the word,But I want particularly  the reason for such practice and origin of it.